# Циклы в php

Tags: php, циклы

Не могу понять использования циклов. Все показывают примеры с числами, это понятно, даже проблем не возникло, а с информацией как? Вот, [к примеру](http://pishemsite.ru/php/Kak-sdelat'-dinamicheskiy-sayt-ispol'zuya-MySQL), как я понимаю, идет условие  `if(!$query){` и т.д.  `else{` потом еще раз `if`, не могу понять последовательность или как правильно это объяснить

```
<?php
function GetDataArt($art_id)
{
    $sel   = "SELECT `title`,`page_title`,`meta_d`,`meta_kw`,`content` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = '$art_id' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sel);
    if (!$query) {
        echo ('Не удалось взять данные из БД!');
    } else {
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            $res        = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $title      = $res['title'];
            $page_title = $res['page_title'];
            $meta_kw    = $res['meta_kw'];
            $meta_d     = $res['meta_d'];
            $content    = $res['content'];
        } else {
            $title      = 'К сожалению, такая страница отсутствует на данном сайте!';
            $page_title = 'К сожалению, такая страница отсутствует на данном сайте!';
            $meta_kw    = $meta_d = $content = '';
        }
        $data_arr = array(
            $title,
            $page_title,
            $meta_kw,
            $meta_d,
            $content
        );
        return $data_arr;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь оформлением кода, тяжело прочитать, что вы написали.

Comment: @Ruta Уточните, в чем собственно вопрос.

Comment: А при чем тут циклы?

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetDataArt($art_id){
   $sel = "SELECT `title`,`page_title`,`meta_d`,`meta_kw`,`content` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = '$art_id' LIMIT 1";
   $query = mysql_query($sel);
  if(!$query){ // если запрос был НЕ удачен то ошибку выводим
    echo('Не удалось взять данные из БД!');
  }
  else{ // запрос выполнился удачно, что-то делаем
    // добавляем еще одно условие на проверку того что мы вообще выдернули что-то из БД или нет
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){ // если кол-во выдернутых строк по запросу больше 0 т.е. там есть хоть одна строка то что-то чему-то присваиваем.
      $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      $title = $res['title'];
      $page_title = $res['page_title'];
      $meta_kw = $res['meta_kw'];
      $meta_d = $res['meta_d'];
      $content = $res['content'];
    }
    else{ // если нет ни одной строки выдернутой из БД то выводим сообщение с ошибкой
      $title = 'К сожалению, такая страница отсутствует на данном сайте!';
      $page_title = 'К сожалению, такая страница отсутствует на данном сайте!';
      $meta_kw = $meta_d = $content = '';
    }
    $data_arr = array($title, $page_title, $meta_kw, $meta_d, $content);
    return $data_arr;
  }
}
?>
```

Еще вопросы :)

ps а циклы то тут причем, тут функция и работа с БД.

pps

я бы немного переписал ф-ю

```
function GetDataArt($art_id){
   $data_arr=0;
   $sel = "SELECT `title`,`page_title`,`meta_d`,`meta_kw`,`content` FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = '$art_id' LIMIT 1";
   $query = mysql_query($sel);
  if(!$query){ // если запрос был НЕ удачен то ошибку выводим
    echo('Не удалось взять данные из БД!');
    return $data_arr;  // вернуть то что-то по любому нужно, результат работы функции потом проверить на "вшивость"
  }
```

т.е. функция отработала, но в первом случае при невыполнении запроса ничего не вернет, следовательно , там где она будет вызвана, возможны последующие ошибки, а результат того что возвратила она я бы все равно проверил.

Answer (score 1):

Переводите слово if - как "если", а слово else как "иначе" и читайте код, тогда всё станет понятно. Наверное, вы имеете ввиду не последовательность, а скорее всего - вложенность.

P.S. Если я права, то все супермозги которые дали ответ ранее, слишком буквально поняли вопрос. :) На то они и супер. :)

Comment: Так они же привели правильный код, нет? Просто поправили, что тут не циклы.

Comment: @Construct, просто я не вижу что вопрос про конкретный код. По-моему, вопрос про основы. Философский, как бы. :)